# Need to use both button and paperclip on ATX connector to power the pc

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

I have some issue on a computer, and after several tests I found out that the only way to safely turn on the computer (otherwise it is dead) is to keep the paperclip on the atx connector and push the button on the front panel. This is the only way to fully boot the computer. After the computer is booted, I can take out the paperclip.
The motherboard has already been replaced once.
It is a PSU issue? What is going wrong?

Comment: Just replace the ATX power cable, sounds like the cable is defective, the paperclip is completing the circuit but having such a low quality metal doing so is just asking for trouble.

Comment: do you have a spare power supply?  or another computer to borrow it from?  If so, test it with a different PSU

Comment: Terix - Did you figure out exactly what your issue was? I'm having the exact same situation, & using a spare power supply cord from another computer makes no difference, so I'm wandering if your situation was what Ramhound said, or something else.

Comment: I've made an offical answer for this, and it's not good news. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is a symphtom of a failing PSU. After a couple of weeks of this mess, the PSU failed completely and died.